# How to map an image on a partial sphere in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created a full sphere out of sphere tiles, to handle all of them individually when they are inside the FOV.

To do that I divided an equirectangular panorama into a few quadratic images to map them onto these tiles. But somehow the texture is shifted on the highest and lowest row of segments in every tile.

Example with some imported sqare images:

[image: shifted tiles]

The original test image:

[image: shifted tiles]

How can I geht the textures map correctly to the tiles? The code for creating the tiles is below:

```
/*
    segment Data:
    x/y are generated by a loop
    maxX/maxY are the maximum values of these loops
*/
sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 4, 4, segmentData.x * 2 * Math.PI / segmentData.maxX, 2 * Math.PI / segmentData.maxX, segmentData.y * Math.PI / segmentData.maxY, Math.PI / segmentData.maxY);
texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(tileImagePath);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

I'm quite new to three.js so maybe this is a very simple problem.

Hopefully somebody can help?

Comment: There is a bug in the current three.js release (r104). I've created an [issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/16454) about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [ScieCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2620080/sciecode), it turned out, that the problem was caused by a bug in versions r103 and r104.

It will be fixed in the next release: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/16454